# Firefox position: absolute not returning expected results

Tags: html, css, firefox

I want to overlay a label on a picture in my webpage. Using position: absolute on the label and float: left on the img, I got it to work in all the browsers that I tested it on--other than Firefox (3 and 4).

Here is what the html will basically look like:

```
<h3>Header</h3>

<div class="wrapper">   
    <span class="img-title">OVERLAY LABEL</span>    
    <img src="pic.jpg">
    <div class="text">
        <p>Some text about the lovely picture goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Footer bits</p>
```

and the CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    overflow: auto; 
}
.img-title { 
    position: absolute; 
}
img { 
    float: left; 
}
```

Can some one clue me in on why Firefox is behaving differently than Chrome, IE, Safari, and Opera in regards to position:absolute?

Here is [my jfiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrmy/7vev8/6/)?

Comment: Jeremy, I also edited the answer to help with your text issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify more than that.

```
.wrapper { 
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow: auto; 
    position: relative;
}
.img_title { 
    position: absolute; 
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}
img { 
    float: left; 
}
```

To position image_title absolutely, but relative to the wrapper, the wrapper must be positioned relatively. Additionally, you must also specify the top and left position of the absolutely positioned title.

**Update**
Your text doesn't appear at the top, aligned with your image, because the `<p>` tag has some padding or margin on it.  You can fix it by:

```
.text p {
    margin: 0; padding: 0
}
```